# Graphene with onsite coulombic term

Tags: graphene

Why is it that when you add the onsite coulombic term in graphene,the mass term is multiplied by Pauli matrix in z direction?Had it been multiplication by identity matrix,then youget the same diagonal terms.But,since it is multiplied by Pauli matrix,the mass term for A site and B site are now exactly negative to each other.Please clarify

Comment: Welcome to Physics-SE. Please add, if possible, a reference to the publication on which your question is based. You could also spell out your problem more explicitly by using MathJax to input the hamiltonian that you are thinking about.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~pjh/teaching/phz7427/7427notes/ch6.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjcgfGV1cfgAhXFabwKHSXqDb0QFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw2DhdirfhBF6r550ayYW2bB

Comment: The source that you gave does not say anything about Coulomb. It simply adds a 'hypothetical' mass term (a toy parameter for theoreticians). In real world graphene, this mass term is zero.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://physics.ipm.ac.ir/conferences/16thspring/pdf/qaiumzadeh.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiv3OnOhcjgAhVyIqYKHa3rBycQFjABegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2A-D765RIxUGuYeobLBSQn